# Pod install clone the repository multiple times if you use single repo for multiple Podspecs

Tags: cocoapods

Hi I have a problem with my repository. I am using single repo for multiple frameworks.

```
+-- Framework1.podspec
+-- Framework2.podspec
+-- libs
|   +-- Framework1
|   |   +-- File.swift
|   +-- Framework2
|   |   +-- File.swift
```

`Framework1.podspec` points `File.swift` that under the `Framework1` folder

`Framework2.podspec` points `File.swift` that under the `Framework2` folder

In a sample project I am using both

```
pod Framework1
pod Framework2
```

When I run `pod install --verbose` I am seeing that the entire repository is being downloaded twice which is a problem to me because both File.swifts are huge (around 200mb).

Is there a way to download the repository only once?

P.S. I tried to use subspecs but it didn't work. I got duplicated file `File.swift` error.